# SQL Server : JOIN two tables and last column COUNT total occurences (by year, zip)

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, count

I have a `Housing` and a `Crime_Reports` table in my SQL Server database. I am trying to count the total occurrences of crimes in the zipcode of a house was sold in with a single query.

There are many values in these tables, but the below is what I am joining on and matching by zip and year (the 'unique' ids between each table are totally different, the below is just an example).

My `Housing` table sample data:

| uID | zipcode | saleyear | soldprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2018 | 300000 |
| 2 | 23345 | 2019 | 200000 |
| 3 | 56777 | 2018 | 500000 |
| 4 | 65789 | 2021 | 350000 |

My `Crime Reports` table sample data:

| IncidentID | zipcode | occurredyear |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2018 |
| 2 | 23345 | 2019 |
| 3 | 56777 | 2018 |
| 4 | 65789 | 2020 |

I want to create a view table (from single query) with the crime occurrences counting the crimes at the house zip code that occurred that year:

| uID | zipcode | saleyear | soldprice | Crime Occurrences At Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2018 | 300000 | 23 |
| 2 | 23345 | 2019 | 200000 | 4 |
| 3 | 56777 | 2018 | 500000 | 50 |
| 4 | 65789 | 2021 | 350000 | 2 |

I tried the following, but this did not work:

```
SELECT 
    h.uID, h.zipcode, h.saleyear, 
    COUNT(c.IncidentID) AS Crime Occurrences At Zip
FROM 
    Housing h
INNER JOIN 
    Crime_Reports c ON h.zipcode = c.zipcode
                    AND h.saleyear = c.occurredyear
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    1
```

**EDIT**

Answers tested and posted below

Comment: `GROUP BY h.uID, h.zipcode, h.saleyear ORDER BY h.uID, h.zipcode, h.saleyear` you can't just do `GROUP BY 1`, also all columns not in an aggregation function must be in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: That worked Charlieface!  Gosh I feel silly, I kept thinking I could use 1,2,3 or 1 etc. instead of calling them exactly

Comment: Some RDBMSs do allow it, such as Postgres, but not SQL Server. Please put your solution in an answer, not in the question. You are welcome to answer your own

Comment: Will do, solutions posted in answer

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE ANSWERS**

**SOLUTION 1** Thanks to @Charlieface (The problem was using 1 or 1,2,3 in BY Clauses)

```
 SELECT h.uID, h.zipcode, h.saleyear, COUNT(c.IncidentID) AS Crime Occurrences At Zip
   FROM Housing h
   INNER JOIN Crime_Reports c
            ON h.zipcode = c.zipcode
            AND h.saleyear = c.occurredyear
 GROUP BY h.uID, h.zipcode, h.saleyear
 ORDER BY h.uID, h.zipcode, h.saleyear
```

**SOLUTION 2** Thanks to @Aiden Or

```
WITH CrimesCTE AS (
    SELECT COUNT(IncidentID) AS CrimeOccurrencesAtZip, occurredyear, zipcode 
    FROM Crime_Reports
    GROUP BY occurredyear, zipcode
)
    
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM Housing) h
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT CrimeOccurrencesAtZip, occurredyear, zipcode FROM CrimesCTE) c
        ON h.zipcode = c.zipcode 
        AND h.saleyear = c.occurredyear
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Common Table Expressions (CTE) in this circumstances :

[SQL Server Common Table Expressions (CTE)](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-common-table-expressions-cte/)

```
 With CTE AS (
    SELECT 
    COUNT(IncidentID) AS Crime Occurrences, 
    occurredyear, 
    zipcode 
    FROM Crime_Reports 
    GROUP BY occurredyear, zipcode)
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * FROM Housing
    ) tb1 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  
            Crime Occurrences,
            occurredyear, 
            zipcode 
        FROM CTE
   ) ON tb1.zipcode = tb2.zipcode 
        AND tb1.saleyear = tb2.occurredyear
```

Comment: Tested and worked!  Thank you [@Aiden Or]